# Internet access with X forwarded session over ssh

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ssh, remote

Having trouble getting internet access in my X forwarded session. Anyone have thoughts? When I try to connect the host to wifi, it appears to run through the connection process... and connect? But the icon doesn't change, and nothing loads in a browser window.

I am running the X forwarded session over ssh through a static ip on the ethernet port.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was two fold. The wifi logo wasn't loading correctly, and needed to be fixed AND the ethernet static IP address knocks out internet access but keeps connection locally to the network. The latter is somewhat expected with this setup, but unintended. Fine for my purposes however.